# Compressing raw frames in a very low bandwidth scenario

Tags: embedded, video-streaming, real-time

**Edit: Comments noted I should clarify where help is needed**

Given the conditions

- 32byte packets some of which can be lost
- 2Mbps maximum speed
- C++ for capturing, sending and possibly processing

How can I compress each frame to achieve decent fps and see objects?

Scenario is about driving fpv, quality is not important as long as you can see what you're doing, reactivity is

---

I'm experimenting with an RC car and looking for a way to transfer real time video data from the car to display.

So far, I'm able to get the raw frames from a usb webcam, in YUV format and convert each to RGB using a raspberry pi 3b in a C++ array, via v4l2, and transfer data through c++ RF24 library

Compressed data will be piped through a pair of NRF24L01+ modules, which have a maximum rate of 2MBits (airtime modulation), so I'm aware that there's very restricted bandwidth available.
After this initial transfer, data will be redirected via usb serial or the bluetooth module HC-05 to my custom android app

- Streaming through these modules has been demonstrated using HEVC, which was a preprocessed clip rather than a real-time application
- I'm not streaming over the network or using a network driver unlike the demonstration, that's why I think a low-end video stream is possible

The solution I'm looking for:
A realtime, extremely compressed stream that's the bare minimum and fast enough to see where the car is going and react, no interest for colors or resolution, wireframe could be okay too.
Each stream packet is limited to a maximum length of 32bytes. And must be recomposed in Java (for the android app)

Solutions I've tried:

- compressing to 8bit colors, unable to put packets together android side
- Uncompressed streaming, just low resolution: slow frametime (about a couple seconds per frame)

Comment: What is your question? Or do you just confirm that a slow connection is slow?

Comment: My question is right before the tried solutions: given the conditions (32byte packets some of which can be lost, 2mbit maximum speed, c++ for capturing, sending and possibly processing) how can I compress each frame to achieve decent fps and see objects 
Scenario is about driving fpv, quality is not important as long as you can see what you're doing, reactivity is

Comment: Here is some added context of a similar question, here I'm looking into a particular approach.

Linking to the closest answer I was looking for
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/61640/154238

Comment: Typical compression is done by `mpeg2`, `divx`, and `mpeg4` encoders/decoders. They allow kbps transmission speeds, providing you can encode/decode fast enough, which is not a great deal, an old "pentium" CPU did it.

Comment: I would need a network connection to create such stream easily though, I only have the ability to send packets of capped length, some of which will be lost in action.

Looks like h264 streams via ffmpeg and raspberry pi are laggy due to the usb webcam (while raspivid with the pi camera seems to work perfectly)

Comment: @LollosoSi The project you linked to that has the link to the drone stuff is by far the best you can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> So far, I'm able to get the raw frames from a usb webcam, in YUV
> format and convert each to RGB using a raspberry pi 3b in a C++ array,
> via v4l2, and transfer data through c++ RF24 library

When you've raw YUV frames, you don't need to convert it to RGB when you've low transmission rate and that your need doesn't pertain to graphics usage. YUV format has already reduced size by removing some of the visual (human) redundancy seen in RGB data. A further sub-sampled color-format (if it's not already) may help you reduce input frame size further.

> bare minimum and fast enough to see where the car is going and react,
> no interest for colors or resolution, wireframe could be okay too

Your question is rather open ended. So, here I'm putting specificity to your requirement:

Consider "raw" CIF video quality (352x288) input frames for example. This will require roughly 1.2 Mb per frame even if input is subsampled to YUV 420. And, if you care about just 30 fps video to understand where the car is going, you'd need (1.2 x 30) Mb per second. This will be a lot of bytes per second and this is where you'd need a codec to encode video frames before transmitting. RF library, IMO, doesn't compress. Since you barely care about video formats/resolution etc.,, most of the available codec today will fully meet your requirement.

What you'll need:

1. You'd need a codec (SW or HW) that converts input YUV to compressed bitstream (AV/HEVC etc.,). With 2 Mbps transmission capability you'll be able to transmit pretty reasonable resolution video. This isn't low bandwidth :)
2. Use your tool/libs for transmission.
3. On Android side, you can write an app that uses MediaExtractor/MediaCodec to extract and decode transmitted/compressed data. You can use the decoded data for any purpose of yours.

Comment: I think this will be the answer. 

Will the stream packets fit in 32 bytes?

If not, I should use the radios as a bridge, but what happens to the decoder if some packets are lost (or half delivered) this way?

Comment: One'd generally use some streaming protocol such as HLS or MPEG-DASH for that purpose. Streaming packets (called NALU) will be larger than 32 bytes for sure but it'll be handled when you stick to any of the protocol.